# Endomorphism between direct sum of modules $M := M_1 \oplus M_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules, multilinear-algebra, free-modules

$\DeclareMathOperator\Hom{Hom}\DeclareMathOperator\End{End}$Let $M_1$, $M_2$ be a $R$-modules and $M := M_1 \oplus M_2$ if $ \pi_1$, $\pi_2$ are the respectives projections and any $ \phi \in \End_R(M)$ has a form $$ \phi = \sum_{i = 1}^{2} \sum_{j = 1}^{2} \pi_i \phi \pi_j $$
We define  $\phi_{ij} =  \pi_i \phi \pi_j|_{M_j}$, I need to show that the morphism
$$ \rho:  \End_R(M) \to  {M_{2\times2}(\Hom_R(M_j, M_i))}$$
given by $\rho(\phi) = \begin{bmatrix}
    \phi_{11}      & \phi_{12}   \\
    \phi_{21}      & \phi_{22}  \\    
\end{bmatrix}$

is a isomorphism to rings.

I showed $\rho( \phi + \psi) = \rho( \phi) + \rho(\psi)$ and also showed that is surjectivity and injectivity buy i not can show that $\rho (\phi \circ \psi) = \rho (\phi) \rho(\psi) $, I try the direct calculus but apparently it is not the way.

some help?

thank

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of $\phi_{ij}$ is wrong.
Let $\varkappa_j:M_j\to M$ be the inclusion morphism into the direct sum and define $\phi_{ij}=\pi_i\circ\phi\circ\varkappa_j:M_j\to M_i$.
Then we have
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\phi_{11}&\phi_{12}\\
\phi_{21}&\phi_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\psi_{11}&\psi_{12}\\
\psi_{21}&\psi_{22}
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\phi_{11}\circ\psi_{11}+\phi_{12}\circ\psi_{21}&\phi_{11}\circ\psi_{12}+\phi_{12}\circ\psi_{22}\\
\phi_{21}\circ\psi_{11}+\phi_{22}\circ\psi_{21}&\phi_{21}\circ\psi_{12}+\phi_{22}\circ\psi_{22}
\end{bmatrix}$$
but since $\varkappa_1\circ\pi_1+\varkappa_2\circ\pi_2=\mathrm{id}_M$,
we get
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\phi_{11}&\phi_{12}\\
\phi_{21}&\phi_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\psi_{11}&\psi_{12}\\
\psi_{21}&\psi_{22}
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
(\phi\circ\psi)_{11}&(\phi\circ\psi)_{12}\\
(\phi\circ\psi)_{21}&(\phi\circ\psi)_{22}
\end{bmatrix}$$
for
\begin{align}
\phi_{i1}\circ\psi_{1j}+\phi_{i2}\circ\psi_{2j}
&=\pi_i\circ\phi\circ\varkappa_1\circ\pi_1\circ\psi\circ\varkappa_j+\pi_i\circ\phi\circ\varkappa_2\circ\pi_2\circ\psi\circ\varkappa_j\\
&=\pi_i\circ\phi\circ(\varkappa_1\circ\pi_1+\varkappa_2\circ\pi_2)\circ\psi\circ\varkappa_j\\
&=\pi_i\circ\phi\circ\psi\circ\varkappa_j\\
&=(\phi\circ\psi)_{ij}
\end{align}